# Bash function inside function: How to interpolate certain variables from outer function

Tags: bash, function, variable-substitution

I'm trying to create a function that creates a function. I want to "hardcode" an argument in the inner function based on what is passed into the outer function, *e.g.*

```
outer() {
    inner() { doSomething --context=$1 $@ }
}
```

Given the above, on calling

```
outer foo
```

I want the inner function's definition to be as if I ran

```
inner() { doSomething --context=foo $@ }
```

In other words, interpolate the outer function's $1 for the definition of the inner function, but leave $@ to be interpolated when calling the inner function.

How can I achieve this?

---

**Edit**, for those wondering about my usecase:

I'm working with a command-line tool with subcommands, *e.g.*

```
doSomething dothis somearg
doSomething dothat
```

It always needs a context flag though, *e.g.*

```
doSomething --context foo dothis somearg
doSomething --context foo dothat
```

And usually once I'm in a context, my next several commands will use the same context.

So the ideal solution would allow me to set the context once and use the inner function like an alias that already knows its context:

```
outer foo
inner dothis somearg
inner dothat
```

This could have also been done with an environment variable, *e.g.*

```
alias inner="doSomething --context=$CONTEXT"
```

But in reality there are 2 flags not 1, and this (now with realistic args)—

```
outer gke_gke-xpn-1_europe-west1_europe-west1-s41l stats_service
inner dothis somearg
inner dothat
```

—is just a little more friendly to use (for me) than—

```
CONTEXT=gke_gke-xpn-1_europe-west1_europe-west1-s41l
NAMESPACE=stats_service
inner dothis somearg
inner dothat
```

Comment: Relating, on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48478586/10488700

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I actually figured it out after an hours' tinkering. The key was to use `eval` and escape the variables that should delay interpolation. If there are better ways though, I want to know! So please add an answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
outer() {
    eval "inner() { doSomething --context=$1 \$@ }"
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a function here? Just `eval "doSomthing..."` would be fine.

Comment: Made an edit to the answer explaining my use case.

Comment: Just note that with the `eval` here, you'll have problems if `$1` contains whitespace or shell special characters. You'd need to wrap it in single quotes and quote any single quotes inside the value to be able to pass arbitrary values. Or, at least check that the value given is "nice", e.g. `case $1 in *[![:alnum:]]*) echo invalid value >&1; return 1;; esac`

Comment: anyway, there are no closures as such in Bash, and all the `eval` does is to redefine the function. So I wonder, why not just set a global variable and refer to _that_ in `inner`?

Comment: The clarifications should ideally have been added to the _question_, not the answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda - Good point, moved. \@ikkachu - Global variable works too; but I had more than 1 flag, and it just feels easier to use an outer command to set things up than manually set 2 global vars. To each their own though!

Comment: This is an _incredibly_ bad idea. It doesn't just pass `$1` through as data; it _interprets as code_, so if your context contains `$(rm -rf ~)`, your home directory gets deleted.

Comment: Also, unquoted `$@` acts just like unquoted `$*`: it string-splits arguments instead of keeping them intact, and then expands each result of that splitting as a separate glob expansion.

Comment: If you insist on doing this, at least change the `$1` to `${1@Q}`; that restricts compatibility to bash 5.0 or newer, but fixes the security issues.

Comment: Also, you need a `;` or newline before the `}` closing the definition of `inner` -- otherwise it's treated as an argument to `doSomething` instead of as syntax.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to create a function that creates a function. I want to "hardcode" an argument in the inner function based on what is passed into the outer function,

What you want is a closure, and I don't think there are those in Bash.

Just use another global variable for the "context" that inner function runs in. E.g.

```
context=
outer() {
    context=$1
}
inner() {
    if [ -z "$context" ]; then
        echo "context not defined" >&2
        return 1;
    fi
    doSomething --context="$context" "$@"
}
```

If you need two context variables, just add another one.

Note that you should quote both `"$context"` and `"$@"` to make sure values with whitespace or glob characters are not mangled due to word-splitting.

Answer (score 0):

That is how it is done in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
outer() {
    # define inner function
    inner() {
        echo 1=$1 2=$2 
    }

    # call inner function
    inner $1 $2
}

# this would give an error, 
inner foo 123

# call outer function.
outer bar 456

# now the inner function is defined and ready to be used by itself
inner baz 789
```

Comment: This didn't quite work for me but I think I underspecified my problem in the question. I will edit.

Comment: Ah I see what I didn't communicate. I didn't want to call `inner` at the time of calling `outer`—I wanted`inner` to be a delayed evaluation using args supplied later.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to do, other than obscure the code and make sure that `inner` is called at least once after defined. The function `inner` that results is as independent from the function `outer` as any other. Note how the values (`bar` and `456`) don't matter at all when calling `inner` itself at the end.

Comment: The lack of quoting is problematic here. `inner "$1" "$2"` or just `inner "$@"` will hold your arguments together, preventing them from being substituted to globbing and expansion.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, this works:

```
outer() { . <( echo "inner() { doSomething $1 $2;  }" ); }
```

Comment: Please explain the "trick" (with `source` / `.`) you're using and why this is better (or at least different) than the suggested use of `eval`.

Comment: ...it certainly has all the same vulnerabilities `eval` has, and it also adds some portability problems (in a few older versions of bash you couldn't successfully `source` a process substitution).

Comment: It's basically the same as `eval`. I feed a string I built myself to the shell to execute as a command. The difference is just that I was able to find a working formulation for `source` but not for `eval`. At the time I posted the answer, the `eval` solution wasn't posted yet.